# How to assemble ARM instructions (using GCC)

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, ida

I want to assemble `ARM` instructions (= converting the textual assembly instructions to machine code).

I tried using [`IDA Pro`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida) to disassemble an `ARM` binary but upon assembling it told me:

```
Sorry, this processor module doesn't support the assembler.
```

Then [I downloaded an `ARM` `gcc`](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) but trying to assemble with it also fails:

```
>gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-win32\arm-none-eabi\bin\as asm.s -o asm.o
asm.s: Assembler messages:
asm.s:1: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov W8,#0x80'
```

Why is the syntax invalid when `IDA Pro` shows instructions exactly like that?
Does this `gcc` not support this `ARM` dialect or do I need a certain command line switch to make it work?

```
Processor       : ARM
ARM architecture: metaarm
Target assembler: Generic assembler for ARM
Byte sex        : Little endian
```

Comment: `w8` indicates `aarch64` binary. You should use `aarch64` toolchain

Comment: aarch64-whatever-whatever-gcc not arm-whatever-whatever-gcc for aarch64

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Thank you, that worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the comments, [downloading the `aarch64` toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads) did the trick:

[image]